# loop through nested QHash with foreach

Tags: c++, qt, foreach, qhash

I have `QHash<QString, QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*>  myNestedQHash;` and when I try

```
foreach (QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*>  stat, myNestedQHash.values(someStr))
```

I get

```
error: macro "Q_FOREACH" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
```

Isn't it possible to loop on nested QHash they way I did?

Comment: This is a problem with the QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*> type definition for stat. try setting this in brackets, i remember having the same problem but i just do not recall ho i solved this.

Comment: if I `typedef QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*> statType` then it should work, but I was wondering why this doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not using

```
for (QHash<QString, QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*>::iterator it = myNestedQHash.begin(); it != myNestedQHash.end(); ++it) 
{...}
```

instead? i think `Q_FOREACH` will create a copy, so it will be better performance as well...

/edit:

the foreach is just a definition for the Q_FOREACH macro ... so the compiler sees it and it will accept 2 values. since you have a additional comma in it, it will see 3 arguments. you will find all infos [here](http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/).

Comment: you're right, and I did the same to loop through my nested QHash, but I wanted to know why can't I use foreach, I mean what is the problem there, rather than how to loop on a nested QHash.

Comment: the `foreach` is just a definition for the `Q_FOREACH` macro ... so the compiler sees it and it will accept 2 values. since you have a additional comma in it, it will see 3 arguments. you will find all infos here: http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/ ;)

Comment: cheers, put your comment as an edit in your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Qt container copies are lightweight, copy-on-write objects so there's negligible performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Should be working like this:

```
QHash<QString, int> myHash0;
myHash0["test0"]=0;
myHash0["test1"]=1;
QHash<QString, int> myHash1;
myHash1["test0"]=0;
myHash1["test1"]=1;

QHash<QString, QHash<QString, int> > myHashList;
myHashList["Hash0"] = myHash0;
myHashList["Hash1"] = myHash1;

QHash<QString, int> h;
foreach(h , myHashList)
{
    qDebug()<<h["test0"];
}
```

Comment: I kinda used QString/int now... lazy typer :) But it should work as soon as you take away the ``QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*> stat`` away from the foreach macro

Answer (score 0):

QT `foreach` is a macro. And parameters in a macro are separated by comma `,`

In your case, you use a template with comma inside.

You can write it as:

```
QHash<quint64, QElapsedTimer*>  stat;  
foreach (stat, myNestedQHash.values(someStr))
```